# Locate CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION in devel space

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that needs some binary resources at run-time.

In CMakeLists.txt, I install:

```
install(
        DIRECTORY resources/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/resources )
```

I would find them in/opt/ros/..../share/pkg/resources.

That works fine when installing the package.

However, how would I locate these resources during development?
They are not installed in the `devel/share` location.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354779/locate-catkin_package_share_destination-in-devel-space/) by [tomlankhorst](https://answers.ros.org/users/55744/tomlankhorst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-06-12**:
Previously asked here: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/1099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on your programming language there is API to get the path of your package which is the directory containing the `package.xml` file: see https://wiki.ros.org/Packages#Client_Library_Support

Python:

```
import rospkg
rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
rospack.get_path('your_package_name')
```

C++:

```
#include <ros/package.h>
std::string path = ros::package::getPath("your_package_name");
```

And in your case the relative path of `resources` is the same so you should be easily able to construct the path you want which works for both cases - the devel / src as well as the install space.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1